# How can I see the number of questions that a given user voted to close but got later reopened by someone else?

Tags: support, data-explorer, reopened-questions

I wonder the following: for a given user, how can I see the number of questions that they voted to close, but the question was later reopened by someone else (possibly a group of users)?

Answer (score 9):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1821849/questions-closed-by-a-specific-user-which-were-later-reopened?UserId=178179) should do the job - at least for questions which were actually closed by the given user (close votes may age away). You have three questions here which fit the bill:

[image]

I don't need to tell you, but it's certainly possible that a question is rightfully closed at first, then edited into a reasonable shape, and later reopened. One should not judge users for the amount of questions this query reports for them :)

Comment: Neat, now i have a list of questions to go flag